# Do i have to license the meme song this is sparta?

Tags: music, licensing

I would like to use this song for my game as easter egg. Where can I license it?

Comment: Also, [under US copyright law](https://www.copyright.gov/music-modernization/educational-materials/Sampling-Interpolations-Beat-Stores-and-More-An-Introduction-for-Musicians-Using-Preexisting.pdf) 1) "fair use" is evaluated on a case-by-case basis, there is no formula to ensure that amount of a work may be used without permission & 2) copyright infringement does not require proof of intent; disclaimers are an internet myth. That's all likely scattered under other answers, here - repeating it because is comes up time & time again.

Comment: "Do I have to license this content" if it was made by someone other than you, and not released under a permissive licence like CC0 or so old as to be in public domain, yes. This is as true in game development as elsewhere. How to go about licensing this particular piece of audio is not a question about how to make a game. You'd likely want to consult with audio/intellectual property experts on that topic. Or consider making your own track that will remind a player of this one, without copying/sampling it directly.

Comment: Also it's important to keep in mind, sites like YouTube have different copyright laws, for example you can _generally_ repost copyright songs on YouTube without any issues (you might get demonetized) whereas in something like a game, you can easily get into trouble, even with something like a meme that may be reposted everywhere.

Comment: @Pow It's not that the law is different. It's that YouTube implements policies for how to handle copyright disputes that don't require going to court to adjudicate each case. Posting copyrighted material on YouTube is just as illegal as using it in your game; it's just easier for a rights-holder to file a demonetization / takedown request than to serve you with a lawsuit, so they take that path of least resistance. When you publish your own game, their only option is to deal with you directly, via a cease & desist letter or taking you to court.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not super good with law stuff that was just my understanding, but thanks.